Azure DevOps wiki page wronly formats quicklinks when redirecting
We are in the process of updating the internal wiki page of our company.
When we are trying to add links to our NServicebus Endpoints, the format keeps changing when redirecting.
So in the wiki page we have this table setup:
| Endpoint Alpha | [ServicePulse] (http://servicepulse.<domain>.nl/?scu=http://servicepulse.<domain>.nl/api/alpha/&mu=http://servicepulse.<domain>.nl/monitoring/alpha/#/dashboard) |

Now when the link is clicked the following link opens:
http://servicepulse.domain.nl/?scu=http%3A//servicepulse.domain.nl/api/alpha/&mu=http%3A//servicepulse.domain.nl/monitoring/alpha/#/dashboard
Is there a way to omit these reformats from the wiki page?
So the : gets changed up by %3A...
We tried IIS redirecting but as we use different environments it is currently not possible to get it right.
We would expect the formatting not to change if possible.

I could reproduce the issue that the colon marks : were replaced by %3A with the below markdown syntax in a wiki page.
HTML <a href="http://servicepulse.domain.nl/?scu=http://servicepulse.domain.nl/api/alpha/&mu=http://servicepulse.domain.nl/monitoring/alpha/#/dashboard">ServicePulse</a>

MD [ServicePulse](http://servicepulse.domain.nl/?scu=http://servicepulse.domain.nl/api/alpha/&mu=http://servicepulse.domain.nl/monitoring/alpha/#/dashboard)

For this, you may report the problem with the findings in Developer Community - Azure DevOps, where the support team can engage the engineering group for further assistance and insights.
As a possible workaround as of now, you may consider using the markdown widget in team dashboard instead.

